# He is not, like his father, optimistic about future

Tags: negation

The sentence goes,
"He is not, like his father, optimistic about future."
It means he is not optimistic but his father is.
But I dont' understand the logic of negation here because it says'like his father'.
Please explain.

Answer (score 1):

"He is not, like his father, optimistic about future" states that the father in question is also *not* optimistic about the future.
*Like his father* is a non-essential appositive clause (which is why it is set off by commas) and thus can be moved around in the sentence. So, we can rewrite the sentence like this - *Like his father, he is not optimistic about future.*

If we needed to state that the father in question was optimistic about the future we would say, ***Unlike** his father, he is not optimistic about future* or *He is not, unlike his father, optimistic about future.*

Comment: You could use _as his father is_ instead of _like his father_.